# Ensure Wallet consistency

Tags: wallet, security

I have recently migrated machine. I used the Apple Migration Wizard and when it was finished my new machine's copy of Multibit appears to have my BTC within it.

My next task is to wipe the old machine, so I want to be sure that everything is in order before I do that. I just opening Multibit enough to ensure this? Are there anymore checks I can do?

Comment: One way to be extra sure would be to send all your coins to a new address and wait for the transaction to be confirmed.  That will prove that all your private keys were readable and valid.

Comment: Agree with Nate, but beware that this would make any back-ups you took prior to the copy obsolete. Back up your new wallet soon after the coins are confirmed.